# Can Double Glazed units be repaired?

Tags: windows

If a double glazed unit has one of its glass panes shattered can the unit be repaired?

Or does the whole thing need to go in the trash?

I know that a double glazed unit is sealed with inert gas inside etc., so my question is whether the single glass that is still in good condition can be reused to make another unit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much of a window should be replaced](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/how-much-of-a-window-should-be-replaced)

Comment: Just wanted to add that the units are not always filled with an inert gas.  Often it's just air.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot salvage the pane that is not broken.  You will need to order a replacement of exact measurements or bring the sash to a glass supplier so a new sealed and gas filled unit can be made. A double pane that is not sealed will collect condensation and fog up quickly. Not an option.

Comment: This happened to me, and I took the sash off, had them measure it, and had my sealed unit in a week.  Remember that you'll need to block off the hole somehow.